# OCTAVE with enlarging width of elements

Tags: vector, matrix, octave

I have a problem (Octave):
lets say I have   a = 1 2 3 4 5

and I want to add 'b' character to every element in a.. So that I get something like that: a = 1b 2b 3b 4b 5b

How do I do that?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do that, `a` must be defined as a string of characters rather than an array of doubles. There may be a more elegant solution, but the following works:

```
a = num2str(1:5); % '1' is a(1), '2' is a(5), etc...
% a(2) to a(4) are white spaces
for k=2:4:18
    a(k) = 'b';
end
```